# I got a problem in mysql database, i need to get the above average of a field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a problem with gettin above average of numberofcities per country. Let me explain my problem, i have a table named City where has a column name Country, from there i get count the number of cities per country, after that i calculate the average of cities in total, where i get the approximately 13 cities per country. And finally i need to calculate or to get countries which have 10% more cities than average?

This is my query :

```
select avg(country_city_counts.numberofcities) as average -- getting average
from
(
  select Country, count(*) as numberofcities -- getting number of cities per  country    
  from city
  group by Country
  order by Country
) country_city_counts
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide us please with some data to test on? A create and insert scripts or a link to dbfiddle would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select c.*
from (select Country, count(*) as numberofcities,
             avg(count(*)) over () as avg_numberofcities
      from city
      group by Country
     ) c
where numberofcities > numberofcities * 1.1
order by Country
```